# Circle Radius is not coming for gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Gmaps4Rails.circles = [{"lat":50.44444444  , "lon":8.3333333}];
Gmaps4Rails.create_circles();

**when i retrieve the hashMap @circle then only lat and long is coming ....So i am not able to draw the circle ....can anyOne help me Out of this...**

Answer (score 0):

`to_gmaps4rails` doesn't create json for circles, you have to build it yourself.

[Just respect the expected format](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Circles).